# Check if component is added/removed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a bullet system. In it, I should be able to dynamically add/remove "effects" to each bullet. So, if a bullet passes through lava, it should get the "fire effect" that later will apply fire damage to game characters. I'm doing it the simple way first, by just making the effects inherit the MonoBehaviour class.
The thing is, I want other components to listen when an effect is added/removed. Something like this:

```cs
gameObject.OnComponentAdded += AddEffectToList;
```

I tried to google it, and the only viable answer I found was using the Reset() unity function. The problem is that it's called only in editor mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would begin my approach. You would need 2 scritps. Your pre-existing bullet scritp (lets call it Bullet.cs) and the bullet's effect script (lets call it BulletFX.cs).

In the Bullet.cs:

```
private void Start()
    {
        BulletFX bulletFX = GetComponent<BulletFX>();
        bulletFX?.OnFXAdded += bulletFX => Debug.Log($"Effect added:{bulletFX.name}");       
        bulletFX?.OnFXRemoved += bulletFX => Debug.Log($"Effect removed:{bulletFX.name}");        
    }
```

In the BulletFX.cs:

```
public class BulletFX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event System.Action<BulletFX> OnFXAdded;
    public event System.Action<BulletFX> OnFXRemoved;

    public void AddFX() => OnFXAdded?.Invoke(this);
    public void RemoveFX() => OnFXRemoved?.Invoke(this);
}
```

The above is something like a pseudocode to give you a general understanding of the implementation. If you're using it, then you'd probably need to expand on & modify it to fit the rest of your script and needs.

Comment: I was thinking around the corner but actually yes, something is responsible for adding/removing those effects so that something should be able to also trigger an according event! Good thinking

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no, there is no such a built-in option. If you want to do such a thing, you have to implement it yourself.

However, to my mind, it sounds like a thing that should be really fine with the ECS pattern. You can check any existing ECS framework compatible with Unity3d for this. Unity has its own `Entities` package, but I would definitely not recommend it to a novice.

Answer (score 1):

Not build-in no.

But you could instead of `MonoBehaviour` have your own base class like e.g.

```
public abstract class BulletEffet : MonoBehavior
{
    public static event Action<BulletEffect> OnCameAlive;
    public static event Action<BulletEffect> OnDestroyed;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        OnBecameAlive?.Invoke(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        if(gameObject) OnDestroyed?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

You will need to test (only on the phone right now) but this should only trigger the event of the component was removed (destroyed) but not the `GameObject` it is attached to.

This way you can globally listen to

```
BulletEffect.OnBecameAlive += SomeListener;
BulletEffect.OnDestroyed += AnotherListener;
```

---

Otherwise, as in [haris.doku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77521045/7111561), something is adding/removing those effects so that something should be able to also trigger an according event you can listen to.

Answer (score 1):

You should just create the event yourself.

Maybe try `System.Action`.

Might look something like this:

```
class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Action OnComponentAdded;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
        OnComponentAdded?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then you can subscribe and unsubscribe to this event like so:

```
class SubscribingClass : MonoBehavior
{
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        someClass.OnComponentAdded += SubscribingMethod;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        someClass.OnComponentAdded -= SubscribingMethod;
    }

    private void SubscribingMethod()
    {
        // Does something when a component is added to the GameObject with the SomeClass component.
    }
}
```

You could even make the Action static and provide a type to pass to the event when invoked. This means you don't have to keep a reference to each bullet you want to subscribe to. Like so:

```
public static Action<Component> OnComponentAdded
```

Then the invocation would be:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var newComponent = gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
    OnComponentAdded?.Invoke(newComponent);
}
```

Which means you can just change the subcribing class like so:

```
class SubscribingClass : MonoBehavior
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SomeClass.OnComponentAdded += SubscribingMethod;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SomeClass.OnComponentAdded -= SubscribingMethod;
    }

    private void SubscribingMethod(Component component)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{component.name} was added.")
    }
}
```